# Create controller from different classes, WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, controller

I am new in C# and trying to create some controller from my class
But unfortunately it is not showing in the window.
here is my code.

```
<Window x:Class="SWV_IT_V0._2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();
            txtBlock.Text = "Hello 1";
            MainGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock);
            ManageControlers myC = new ManageControlers();
        }
    }
```

---

When run this code I get "Hello 1"  on my window
but when i try to create textblock from my class:

```
namespace SWV_IT_V0._2
{
    public partial class ManageControlers : MainWindow
    {
        public TextBlock txtBlock;
        public ManageControlers()
        {
            txtBlock = new TextBlock();
            txtBlock.Text = "Hello 2";
            MainGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

nothing show in window?
how is it possible to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `InitializeComponent();` to `ManageControlers`constructor.

Through `ManageControlers myC = new ManageControlers();`, you are creating a new instance of your `ManageControlers` window, but you also need to show it via `myC.ShowDialog();`.

Comment: Thanks, it almost helped.
after adding myC.ShowDialog(); I have my controller on the window, but unfortunately the window opens several times at once.

Comment: It opens as often as you call myC.ShowDialog(); plus your MainWindow, so in your case there should be two windows.

Comment: actually i want to add mentioned controllers to my MainWindow.

Comment: You can't add a window to a window, I think what you want to use is a `UserControl`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W